# Can't see anything in Web.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I am trying to make a macOS app using Xcode 12.4 , that opens webpages. When I try to use `Web.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))` , I see an empty window.
I use a WKWebView in Main.storyboard
Here is the ViewController.swift code:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit
let webView = WKWebView()

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Search: NSSearchField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Web: WKWebView!
    var web: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Web.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: In the **App Sandbox** for your project, in the **Signing and Capabilities** section, have you enabled **Outgoing Connections (Client)**?

Comment: Web should be lowercased

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded Outgoing Connections (Client)

Comment: @aheze, web.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)) gives a Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I suggest setting up a `WKNavigationDelegate` for your web view so that you can detect progress and errors.

Comment: You may want to tidy up your code, you have 3 `WKWebView`s. You might also find this link useful https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/112/the-ultimate-guide-to-wkwebview

Comment: Unnest `Web.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))`, on which statement do you get the error? Are the outlets connected in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the simplest solution to this problem: remove the App Sandbox! More information about this here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92265

Comment: Sometimes this won't work, so just duplicate the project, delete the old one, and open the new project again. This just works. No explanation of this (for now...).